# can't build with the latest keil MDK version(V5.37)

Tags: c, arm, keil

all:
I updated my keil MDK version to the latest which is V5.37,and then I found that the project can't build anymore.
since the V5.37 do not support the compiler 5 and set the default compiler to compiler 6,I installed the compiler 5(Arm compiler version 5 ,V5.06 update7) with a independent patch.and then add the compiler 5 to the keil,set the compiler 5 as the default compiler,but keil can't build the project,build output as follows:

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 7 (build 960)', folder: 'C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin'
Build target 'LED'
assembling startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s...
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s: Error: A9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s: Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - Product location: product not found
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s:  - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s: Product: unknown
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s: Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s: Tool: ArmAsm [4d35fa]
compiling delay.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling main.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling stm32f4xx_syscfg.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling usart.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling sys.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling stm32f4xx_rcc.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling stm32f4xx_usart.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling led.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling misc.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling system_stm32f4xx.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 If you need further help, provide this complete error report to your supplier
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling stm32f4xx_gpio.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 If you need further help, provide this complete error report to your supplier
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
compiling stm32f4xx_it.c...
Error: C9511E: Unable to determine the current toolkit. Check that ARM_TOOL_VARIANT is set correctly.
Check that your license details are correct in the License Management dialog of MDK. Additional information is available at:
 If you need further help, provide this complete error report to your supplier
 - ARMLMD_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - LM_LICENSE_FILE: unset
 - ARM_TOOL_VARIANT: unset
 - ARM_PRODUCT_PATH: unset
 - Product location: product not found
 - Toolchain location: C:\_AnZhuang\keil\Keil\ARMCCv506u7\Bin
 - Selected tool variant: mdk_lite
Product: unknown
Component: ARM Compiler 5.06 update 7 (build 960)
Tool: ArmCC [4d365d]
"..\OBJ\LED.axf" - 13 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:01
```

form the build output it means the keil license is incorrent.But I've tried every type license code which are generated by the keygen and all of these license are faild.

so, is there anybody have the same issue as mine? and any solutions or advices to try?
many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, tried to define the path in the environment variable, installing it in different directories,...; None of them worked.

Eventually, faced this page on their own documentation:
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka005073/1-0/?lang=en

Try to install the ARM compiler V5 in this path:
[Keil installation path]\ARM\ARM_Compiler_5.06u7

For me it's:
C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARM_Compiler_5.06u7

Then add the path to Keil's ArmCC Path like this:
[Keil ArmCC Path: add compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egOcj.png)

Comment: I'll have a try. it seems like the answer has been solved

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka005073/latest

Here it says you should not install the compiler to the default directory.

Comment: ok,thans.and I'll have a try